# IEnumerable<T> vs IReadOnlyList<T>

Tags: .net, ienumerable

What is the difference between choosing `IEnumerable<T>` vs `IReadOnlyList<T>` as a return parameter type or input parameter type?

`IEnumerable<T>` provides `.Count` and `.ElementAt` which is what is exposed by `IReadOnlyList<T>`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` represents a forward-only cursor over some data. You can go from start to end of the collection, looking at one item at a time.

`IReadOnlyList<T>` represents a readable random access collection.

`IEnumerable<T>` is more general, in that it can represent items generated on the fly, data coming in over a network, rows from a database, etc. `IReadOnlyList<T>` on the other hand basically represents only in-memory collections.

If you only need to look at each item once, in order, then `IEnumerable<T>` is the superior choice - it's more general.

I'd recommend actually looking at the C++ Standard Template Library - their discussion of the various types of iterators actually maps pretty well to your question.

Comment: I interpret "generated on the fly" as to mean lazily resolved via a "pull" mechanism.