# Block the List.Add() method

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that contains a private List. I have created a getter and a method to add elements to the list:

```
public class Test{

    private List<T> myList;
    public List<T> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
    }

    public Test()
    {
         myList = new List<T>();
    }

    public void AddElements(T element)
    {
         // Do dome stuff, subscribe to an event of T
         myList.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Since everytime an element is added to my list I want to do more things, I do not want that in some part of the code someone add an element directly:

```
Test test = new Test();

// Wrong
test.MyList.Add(element);

// Right
test.AddElements(element);
```

I have thought on creating a new class that implements the IList interface and overrides the Add() method, but I was wondering if there is a more simple/elegant way on "block" this Add() method.

Comment: Don't expose `List` if you don't want someone being able to modify it. You can expose [`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75(v=vs.110).aspx), then no one can add (unless they use reflection).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using at least .NET 4.5, return a `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

```
public class Test{

    private List<T> myList;
    public IReadOnlyList<T> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
    }

    public Test()
    {
         myList = new List<T>();
    }

    public void AddElements(T element)
    {
         // Do dome stuff, subscribe to an event of T
         myList.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen for sure, but there's always a way to get at the data.

Comment: I think this works fine enough and it doesn't create copies. Like you said. "there's always a way to get at the data"   ;-)

Comment: Perhaps it's me but IReadOnlyList don't protect from cast, and it seems you can add with a cast.

Answer (score 5):

I would return as `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`

Use it like:

```
public class Test<T> 
{

    private List<T> myList;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<T> MyList
    {
        get { return myList.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public Test()
    {
        myList = new List<T>();
    }

    public void AddElements(T element)
    {
        // Do dome stuff, subscribe to an event of T
        myList.Add(element);
    }
}
```

This way you prevent casting... It will Wrap your `List<>` with a ReadOnlyCollection class.

---

Or you could return it as an `Array` like:

```
public T[] MyList
{
    get { return myList.ToArray(); }
}
```

**The `ToArray()` method will create a copy of the list**

---

When it is Returned as an `IReadOnlyList<T>`. You could simply cast it back..

```
Test test = new Test<int>();

test.AddElements(10);

((List<int>)test.MyList).Add(20);

foreach(var i in test.MyList)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Test class expose the `List` as `IReadOnlyList<T>` then you wont be allowed to use MyList.Add directly

```
public class Test{

    private List<T> myList;
    public IReadOnlyList<T> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
    }

    public Test()
    {
         myList = new List<T>();
    }

    public void AddElements(T element)
    {
         // Do dome stuff, subscribe to an event of T
         myList.Add(element);
    }
}
```

**Edit** updated it IEnumerable to IReadOnlyList. There are benifits in using IReadOnlyList - [IEnumerable<T> vs IReadOnlyList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855303/ienumerablet-vs-ireadonlylistt)

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for your getter is to add elements you won´t need to directly access the list at all, but you can wrap the call to the `Add`-method into your own method:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> _myList ...

    public void AddElements(T element)
    {
         // Do dome stuff, subscribe to an event of T
         _myList.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Exposing a generic list is furthermore avoided by [CA1002](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use the elements of the list from outside, so I need access to it...